# Card Game Simulator - How To Tell If Card is High Or Low

Tags: java

I am developing a card game.

I have ran into an issue with trying to test whether a card is high or low.

In poker when seeing if someone has a straight. It is all consecutive cards...So 2,3,4,5,6 would be a straight.

But with the ace it can be a high or a low...So it could be Ace,2,3,4,5 or

10, jack, queen, king and Ace.

The problem is I am not sure how to test to see if the ace should be a high or low when it does occur.

I know I could sort the cards and figure it out that way but I am not sure how to sort the cards. Cards are a class and the array used to store the cards is just a basic array.

So how would one go about testing to see if the ace should be a high or low? and if the ace is not their, continue checking if the cards are a straight or not.

Here is the code I have so far, it works for everything except when cards are in the following order: king,Ace,2,3,4. But this sequence is not a straight by poker rules.

Code:

```
public static boolean hasStraight(Card[] cards) {
    // START COUNT AT 1 BECAUSE WE KNOW WE HAVE ATLEAST 1 CONSECTUTIVE
    // NUMBER IN EVERYHAND.
    int count = 1;
    boolean hasStraight = false;
    int lastNum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < cards.length; j++) {

            if (i != j && cards[j].getValue() != lastNum
                    && cards[i].getValue() + 1 == cards[j].getValue()
                    || cards[i].getValue() == 13
                            && cards[j].getValue() == 1) {
                count++;
                lastNum = cards[j].getValue();
            }

        }

    }

    if (count >= 5) {
        hasStraight = true;
    }
    return hasStraight;

}
```

Comment: May I suggest a different algorithm?  (1) Find the smallest card (2) If the smallest card is `n`, see if `n+1`, `n+2`, `n+3`, and `n+4` are in the hand (3) if the smallest card is an ace, make a special check for 10-J-Q-K.  Your approach seems clever, but as you've found out, it doesn't handle the wraparound case well, and it's not clear how to fix it.  So it may be time to try a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my conceptual put-together for this ....

```
static final int LOW_ACE = 0;
static final int HIGH_ACE = 13;

/**
 * Assumes values.size() always == 5
 */
boolean valuesMakeStraight(List<Integer> values) {
    Collections.sort(values);
    int consecutive = values.get(0);
    boolean sofarsogood = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.size() && sofarsogood; i++, consecutive++) {
        sofarsogood = (values.get(i) != consecutive);
    }
    return sofarsogood;
}

// ---------

List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    values.add(cards[i].getValue());
}

boolean isStraight = valuesMakeStraight(values);
// Assumes HIGH_ACE is the default
if(!isStraight && values.contains(HIGH_ACE)) {
    values.remove(HIGH_ACE);
    values.add(LOW_ACE);
    isStraight = valuesMakeStraight(values);
}
```

Comment: It is possible to do it without using List?

Comment: It is quite possible to use an array instead of a list, and then use `Arrays.sort()`

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, the Ace is only considered *low* to complete a straight containing 2,3,4,5.  The only other time you need to worry about an Ace in a straight is to complete 10,J,Q,K.  So that's how you would tell whether to consider it low or high.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The OP knows about this, and he tried to include code to account for it.  But the code is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. I know this. Thats the issue im having with the code above lol

Comment: With the code I have now, king,Ace,2,3,4 is being recognized as a straight